# Why do I keep getting Database Inspector warning?

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-4.2, database-inspector

I changed something in my code (I'm not sure what), and now I get the following warning every time I run the emulator.

```
Database Inspector
For security reasons offline mode is disabled when the process being
inspected does not correspond to the project open in studio or when the
project has been generated from a prebuilt apk.
```

I haven't touched my gradle, nor built an APK. The only other thing that I can think of is that Android Emulator updated to 30.6.5 this morning, but I didn't have this occurring until around lunchtime. What does this actually mean, what might be causing it, and how can I make it go away?

Answer (score -4):

Open "Database Inspector" window, click on the device name, and in drop-menu turn-off process.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: not working still same error